# How to filter through a table with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to filter through an array so that when a certain tab is clicked, only those results show. I have managed to isolate the certain variables I want to remain but the others that don't fit the criteria still remain. How do I get the filter method to actually render on the page so that the results can be shown. I have searched for hours for and have tried to get the tbody and sort through that but I just get confused as I am mostly new to javascript and react. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
Filter Method

const tbody = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')
    console.log(tbody)
    //change active class
    function addTabBackground() {
        const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab]')

        window.onload = function () {
            tabs.forEach(tab => {
                tab.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    if (tab.getAttribute('data-tab') === 'gains') {
                        listOfOptions.map(option => {
                            console.log(option.totalProfit)
                        })
                    }
                    tabs.forEach(tab => {
                        tab.classList.remove('active')
                    })
                    tab.classList.add('active')
                })
            })
        }

    }

<div className="outputs" >
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Stock Name</th>
                            <th>Price Of Option</th>
                            <th>Number Of Options</th>
                            <th>Total Amount Spent</th>
                            <th>Option Sold At</th>
                            <th>Amount Of Options Sold</th>
                            <th>Proft</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    {listOfOptions.map(option => {
                        return (
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{option.clock}</td>
                                    <td>{option.name.toUpperCase()}</td>
                                    <td>${option.price}</td>
                                    <td>{option.amountOfOptions}</td>
                                    <td>${option.totalAmountSpent.toFixed(2)}</td>
                                    <td>${option.optionPriceSoldAt}</td>
                                    <td>{option.amountOfOptionsSold}</td>
                                    <td style={{ color: option.totalProfit >= 0 ? 'green' : 'red' }}>${option.totalProfit.toFixed(2)}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        )
                    })}
                </table>
            </div>
```

Comment: You're fighting against React here. Instead of mucking with the DOM, just use `onClick` props, compute your props dynamically in JSX, and conditionally render entire rows based on state.

Comment: Hi @coreyward, thank you for your answer, but could you explain a little more in depth. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Could you clarify how the tabs are rendered? Are they also react components or is this a legacy app with some raw html elements mixed with react components?

Comment: @AnthonyGarcia-Labiad Hi, they are a react component. They are stored in a component called navbar.

Answer (score 2):

I have used React-Bootstrap-v5 to get Nav, Nav.Item with eventKey and then passed selectedKey in its onSelect function to change the tabs.

Then once we get the data inside my data variable, I used the map function to go over the array. Inside Map Function I have used the required condition to filter the elements i.e. variable = 'Open' or 'Live'.

This will only show the Open type in Open Tab and Live Type Data inside Live Tab.

Hope it's clear to you.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const TestSeries = () => {
 // Declare Variable for data to be fetched from API
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const fetchTestData = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(site_ip + '/apiLink');
    setData(response.data.Content);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTestData();
  }, []);

  // State Variable to keep track of active tab
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState('Open');

  return (
    <>
      <Nav
        activeKey={activeTab}
        fill
        variant="pills"
        onSelect={(selectedKey) => {
          setActiveTab(selectedKey);
        }}
      >
        <Nav.Item>
          <Nav.Link eventKey="Open">Open</Nav.Link>
        </Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Item>
          <Nav.Link eventKey="Live">Live</Nav.Link>
        </Nav.Item>
      </Nav>
      <br />

      <Table striped bordered hover>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th
            <th>Column3</th>
            <th>Column4</th>
            <th>Data Type</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map((item, index) =>
             // Condition by which data will be filtered 
            item.data_type == activeTab ? ( 
              <tr>
                <td>{index + 1}</td>
                <td>{item.col1}</td>
                <td>{item.col2}</td>
                <td>{item.col3} </td>
                <td>{item.col4}</td>
                <td>{item.data_type}</td>
              </tr>
            ) : null
          )}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </>
  );
};

export default TestSeries;
```

Result

[image: Open Type Data]
[image: Live Type Data]

Comment: Please add more clarity to your answer, by explaining what you did, how, so the OP would know how to avoid this mistake next time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from the comment that you have something vaguely looking like:

```
function Page() {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Table />
    </>
  )
}
```

What you need to do is to store the current tab in a `state`, and pass this state down to the Table component so that you can use a [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) when rendering your table.

```
function Page() {
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(DEFAULT_ACTIVE_TAB)
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar activeTab={activeTab} setActiveTab={setActiveTab} />
      <Table activeTab={activeTab} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Your Navbar component should have a onClick handler where it is calling the setActiveTab function when the active tab change.

Then in your Table component you should have something like this:

```
function Table({ activeTab }) {
  return (
   <table>
    ...
   {listOfOptions
     .filter(option => /* something depending on the activeTab */)
     .map(option => <... />)
   }
  </table>
}
```

Comment: So, in this function you would use filter and then map through the answer from filter.

Comment: Then that will render to the page.